# problem with AddHandler in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

i have the .htaccess file included this line

```
<FilesMatch "\.js$">
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .js
</FilesMatch>
```

it works in my localhost but it doesnt work in my host.
i think problem is with mod_mime.
in localhost i see mod_mime in loaded module but in my host (Apache/2.2.16 php 5.3.3) i cant find loaded module to check if it is enable.

1. how to check whether mod_mime is
   in loaded module?
2. how to load
   (enable) mod_mime in htaccess?

Comment: Are you sure that Apache is able to use .htaccess file?
Usually, by default, Apache is not configured to read configuration from .htaccess file

Comment: Try for instance to put a .htaccess file with the directive `Deny from all`. If it works you should get a `401 Unauthorized` code

Comment: to list modules the command is apache2 -M or httpd -M

Comment: where do i enter apache2 -M in my shared host?more information please.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're confusing `AddHandler` with `SetHandler`? It would make more sense to use `SetHandler` in `<Files>`; for `AddHandler` there's no need for your enclosing scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if module loaded with

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
   ...
</IfModule>
```

but you cannot load a module from within .htaccess.

Comment: do you mean <FilesMatch "\.js$"><IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .js </IfModule>
</FilesMatch> ?

Comment: Rather whole FilesMatch section inside IfModule

Comment: Well, of course, since I didn't provide a solution. I just answered your question about loading modules. The solution is just one string.

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .js