# problem with GZIP CKEditor

Tags: javascript, gzip, ckeditor

i want to gzip ckeditor.js  and i changed extension from js to php and added this line to ckeditor.js.php file

```
<?php
ob_start ("ob_gzhandler");
header("Content-type: text/javascript; charset: UTF-8");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
$offset = 60 * 60 ;
$ExpStr = "Expires: " .
gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s",
time() + $offset) . " GMT";
header($ExpStr);
?>
```

this code work for other .js files but this error appear for ckeditor.js.php page:

```
Error: CKEditor not found.This sample assumes that CKEditor (not included with CKFinder) is installed inthe "/ckeditor/" path. If you have it installed in a different place, just editthis file, changing the wrong paths in the <head> (line 5) and the "BasePath"value (line 32).
```

i found ckeditor_php5.php and change 
* $CKEditor->basePath = '/ckeditor/'; to  $CKEditor->basePath = '/ckeditor/ckeditor.js.php'; but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compress static resources it's better to do it via apache [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html). PHP is slow and shouldn't be used for compressing static resources because processing will keep happening no matter how many times the file is requested. Also mod_deflate will handle cases where the client does not support gzip.

In addition in your example you have to modify possibly more than one place in the original code. That means than upgrading ckeditor will be harder later on.

Comment: i have a problem with AddHandler in htaccess file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747830/problem-with-addhandler-in-htaccess

Comment: OK, but my answer presents what you should be doing for the particular question you asked.

Comment: i have ckeditor on another host. i didnt use gzip and deflate for this site. but i checked ckeditor.js file with YSlow  and size is reduced to 110 KB. How host do this?

Comment: @imez: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Please explain.

Comment: sorry for bad english. i have another site on another host. i didnt use deflate or gzip on this site. then why js files have smaller size (i check this with YSLOW addon firefox). do host gzip or deflate js file?

Comment: @imez: maybe the server automatically does this for you.